# TCPDF toc(table of content) with freemono font creating an issue

Tags: php, special-characters, tcpdf

I am creating a PDF which have special character like (≥,≤ etc.) so I am using **freemono** font but it is creating an issue in TOC(*table of content*). In TOC it is displaying page no. 10,11 etc. like {++..}

If I use courier font instead of **freemono** it is working fine but it is not displaying specail character it is shown as **?**.

Comment: Chances to question duplicate click here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141865/tcpdf-html-with-special-characters-displays-empty-pdf-file[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141865/tcpdf-html-with-special-characters-displays-empty-pdf-file)

Comment: My question is different i want to generate PDF only in courier font using special character with TOC.